# Python PIL: Replace Out-of-Range Text with Ellipsis

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pillow to add a line of text on an image, and sometimes the text can be so long that it exceeds the width of the image. In this case, I want to replace the extra chars with ellipsis(...) so that it can just fit into the image.

I'm using `ImageDraw.Draw(img).text(position, inputtext)`. I wonder if Pillow has an automatic way of doing this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in for that.
But it is not all that difficult to write it yourself.

Once you've created a `ImageFont` object, you can use its [`getlength`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getlength) method to query the width in pixels of a text.

If that is longer than the width of the image, shorten the text and try again. Say we have a length of 100 pixels.

```
In [1]: s = 'this is a text that might be too long.'

In [2]: from PIL import ImageFont

In [4]: font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/local/share/fonts/local/Komika.ttf")

In [6]: split = s.split(' ')

In [7]: for i in range(len(split)+1):
   ...:     print(i, font.getlength(' '.join(split[:i])+' ...'))
   ...:     
0 9.0
1 25.0
2 35.0
3 43.0
4 63.0
5 84.0
6 111.0
7 124.0
8 141.0
9 163.0
```

So we can only use 5 words;

```
In [10]: newstring = ' '.join(split[:5])+' ...'

In [11]: font.getlength(newstring)
Out[11]: 84.0

In [12]: newstring
Out[12]: 'this is a text that ...'
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the method. So you mean try the text one char shorter at each iteration until a proper length is found? I'm just wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: I'd probably make it a word shorter at a time. See added example code. It should not be difficult to wrap this up in a function.

Comment: I got this message `DeprecationWarning: getsize is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use getbbox or getlength instead`
So maybe change the function in the example.